# MarkerClusterer loading my map twice

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps for a project, and have successfully implemented the MarkerClusterer Library. My problem is that my map is being loaded **twice** when I start load it in the page.  Here is my JS file so far:

Globals:

```
var map;
var startLatLng = {lat: 37.020098, lng: -101.953125};
var userAncestorMarkers = []; 
var mcOptions = {
    gridSize: 50,
    maxZoom: 15,
    imagePath: '../img/m'
};
```

Initialize my map and obtain markers using AJAX

```
//so i don't have to write document.getElementById all the time
function id(v){
    return document.getElementById(v);
}

//Initialize the mighty google map and perform an AJAX call to obtain data points.
function initMap() {
    //if there is no div#map, abort.
    if(!id('map')) {
        return;
    }
    //initial map options
    var options = {
        center: startLatLng,
        zoom: 3,
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 15,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        styles: ...

    //otherwise, load the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(id('map'), options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        checkBounds(map);
    });

    //obtain the coordinates from table ancestor_origin and create points showing where people currently live.
    downloadUrl("../view-user-ancestor.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var latitude = markers[i].getAttribute("latitude");
            var longitude = markers[i].getAttribute("longitude");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    icon: {
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                        scale: 8.5,
                        fillColor: "#98FB98",
                        fillOpacity: 0.4,
                        strokeWeight: 0.1
                    }
            });
            userAncestorMarkers.push(marker);
            console.log(userAncestorMarkers);
        }
    });

    var userAncestorCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, userAncestorMarkers, mcOptions);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
}


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

// If the map position is out of range, move it back
function checkBounds(map) {
    var latNorth = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    var latSouth = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    var newLat;
    if(latNorth<85 && latSouth>-85)     /* in both side -> it's ok */
    return;
    else {
        if(latNorth>85 && latSouth<-85)   /* out both side -> it's ok */
        return;
        else {
            if(latNorth>85)
            newLat =  map.getCenter().lat() - (latNorth-85);   /* too north, centering */
            if(latSouth<-85)
            newLat =  map.getCenter().lat() - (latSouth+85);   /* too south, centering */
        }
    }
    if(newLat) {
        var newCenter= new google.maps.LatLng( newLat ,map.getCenter().lng() );
        map.setCenter(newCenter);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    initMap();
});
```

Note the last couple of lines. This is where I add my DomListener. If this is outside the function initMap(), I receive an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

How can I initialize my map with markerclusterer without loading my map twice? I know I am calling my function initMap() to run twice, once when the document loads, and once after the document finishes loading, but I can't get markerclusterer to work without the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);` being within initMap().

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    {% include '/includes/head.html.twig' %}
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######"
    async defer></script>
    <script src="/js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

<!-- Load Scripts -->
<script src="/js/googlemaps_view.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you loading the "map" the first time? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I have modified my post to provide a complete example for you. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Doen't look complete to me. What is in `/js/googlemaps_view.js` and `/js/scripts.js`?  Why does this line `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######"
    async defer></script>` have "async defer" but no callback parameter?

Comment: Possibly related question: [Google Maps stops loading when the code is moved to my JS file from script tags in index.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729399/google-maps-stops-loading-when-the-code-is-moved-to-my-js-file-from-script-tags)

Comment: @geocodezip

Thank you for helping me! Pointing me to async defer made me realize that I am mixing my ajax calls. I have three different ajax calls occuring on this map to pull markers from my database. The problem was that I was using only one ajax call with markerclusterer, and the two ajax calls were drawing points on the map without markerclusterer. Because of this, the points map was being initalized twice. 

The other issue was that MarkerCluster was being called after my AJAX call, thus it was using an empty array at start, and then using a full array after the call was completed.